# A peculiar gerund construction

Tags: syntactic-analysis, gerunds

I am unsure how to phrase this as I am uncertain as to whether it is a point of grammar or one of style.

In a book I am reading (by, admittedly, a quite scholarly author), the gerund is *almost* always preceded by the definite article and succeeded by the preposition 'of'.

He would write, for example, that 'The killing of the king' or 'The calling of parliament had three effects.'

In my view, both of these statements can be expressed without this construction ('kiling the king' and 'calling parliament') while not detracting from their meaning.

Accordingly, my question is: Does this structure signifying anything more than a matter of style? Or is it a rule previously observed (the author is a early twentieth-century academic)?

Comment: New one to me. Smoking is prohibited. Eating dessert is optional. Labeling a writer scholarly is open to question.

Comment: It's no different than how or when you would apply articles, definite or indefinite, or not, to any other noun or noun phrase. Note that there is a big difference between ***the*** *killing **of** the king* and *killing the king*. The meaning is significantly changed. The phrasing might be optional, but the phrasing is certainly not just interchangeable.

Comment: Invaluable - thanks to both of you.

Comment: Quirk postulates a multi-point gradience of ing-forms from the deverbal noun (his paintings of the king have been stolen) all the way to the participle (he was painting the king). Some steps along the way are more nouny (the painting of the king is to take place next week), some more verby (slowly painting the king is nerve-wracking).

Comment: "Killing" is unquestionably a noun (or more precisely a gerundial noun) in your example by virtue of the _of_ PP and the determiner _the_. Note also that unlike a verb it can take adjectival premodification, as in, for example, "The tragic killing of the king". The same applies to your other example.

Answer (score -1):

> He would write, for example, that 'The killing of the king' or 'The calling of parliament had three effects.'

It is a point of grammar:

In "The killing of the king" "killing" is **not** a gerund: it is a **verbal noun**.

Verbal nouns are distinguished from gerunds in that they are modified by adjectives "The *cruel* killing of the king would be a good plan."

Gerunds are modified by adverbs "Cruelly killing the king would be a good plan."

Comment: You're using one approach and set of terms. Adherents of CGEL would claim that their terminology and classification are superior, and there are still some of us who think the Quirk noun ... verb gradience of ing-forms a better model (more complex with the pros and cons that allows). But most people on ELU eschew the term 'gerund' as it has so many conflicting definitions. _All this covered here before._

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Astute observations: The acolytes of CGEL are heretics and Quirk's grading is almost perfection. Those who eschew terms usually do so because they have not grasped them or the terms do not accord with their dogma for which, and in this case, there is no explanation for the qualification of a verbal noun by an adjective. I see two approaches: 1. embrace the difference or 2. call everything "the -ing form". The latter explains nothing.

Comment: 'Brown's deftly painting his daughter is a joy to watch' really has the constituency test pundits performing backflips.